# Background app crashing current app

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm building an app that uses the camera. As many know, the camera uses a lot of memory and often throws a memory warning.

The app works well and as expected. However, when streaming Spotify in the background, my app crashes.

Is there any way to stop/pause a background app?

Comment: Check "didReceiveMemoryWarning".

Answer (score 0):

in iOS, every app runs in its own sandbox environment that cannot interact with other apps which are running so there is no way your app can pass on any kind of instruction (pause/stop) to other app running in background.

Comment: That is what I thought, but I figured I'd throw it out there. Thanks.

Comment: Not totally true. If the OP started their own AVPlayer it would invalidate Spotify's and take over the audio output on the device. Then the OP would have the ability to stop his own AVPlayer and thus, stop all instances of AVPlayer running on the device to free up memory.